# Seeking pretty icons for GIS development?

Tags: qgis, development, gui, icon

I am developing GIS software and I want to build a pretty GUI for it.

Where can I found some pretty icons for my GUI?

I mean for example, icons for adding a vector or raster.
I mean icons like [QGIS](http://qgis.org) icons.

[image]

[image]

I searched the web and found [Maki icons](https://www.mapbox.com/maki/) but it was not helpful.

Similar questions:

- [Seeking free map icons sets?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118026)
- [Seeking Good Symbology for Interactive Web Mapping?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6171)

Comment: The icons may (should) be in with the QGIS source code which can be freely downloaded... so long as you don't intend to make profit from your application you shouldn't be breaking any license agreement.

Comment: Codefoster has a general collection of Icons here: http://codefoster.com/media he suggested on IconFinder and choosing free to find good scalable Icons on MVA course. So you could search for map or layers...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are the icons used in the latest QGIS (by default I think) and GRASS GIS:

http://robert.szczepanek.pl/gis-icons-0.1/

They are licensed under the [Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported License](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) which means you can use, alter and share them as long as you attribute the original creator and share your icons under the same or similar license.

Other commonly in web-based GIS application used icons are the GeoSilk icons by OpenGeo:

http://projects.opengeo.org/geosilk

This icon set is licensed under [Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 License](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/) which let you edit and share the icons as long as you attribute the original creator.

Comment: All the icons that we use on QGIS can be found here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/images/themes/default

Comment: Currently the only copy of geosilk I can find is at https://github.com/planetfederal/geosilk/tree/master/silk

Answer (score 1):

There are the [GeoSilk icons](https://github.com/planetfederal/geosilk/tree/master/silk) that are used in GeoServer and I think UDig. They are released under a [CC](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/)-by license.

Answer (score 0):

As @Nathan said, all QGIS icons are in QGIS code source repository in https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/images/themes/default or in a parent folder https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/images

If you are in the context of a QGIS Plugin, you can re-use them in your python plugin directly, without adding the icon itself in your code repository.

For instance if you want the "+" and "-" icons which are used in QGIS, on the right side of the screenshot:

```
QIcon(QgsApplication.iconPath('symbologyAdd.svg'))
QIcon(QgsApplication.iconPath('symbologyRemove.svg'))
```

[image]