# Seeking free map icons sets?

Tags: google-maps, icon

Which is the best source of free map icons (royalty free & price free)?

I need an icon set for my Google Maps project that will give it a custom feel. Ideally I want an icon set with a creative commons license so I can modify them myself.

Comment: An excellent article on the use of map icons: http://cartonerd.blogspot.it/2014/09/on-emoji-cartography.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a post on the [MangoMap blog](http://blog.mangomap.com/post/99289055371/free-map-icons) with an overview of the top 3 free map icons sets.

I particularly like the Map Icon Designer, shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The [Maki](https://www.mapbox.com/maki/) POI icon set (from the crew at MapBox) is pretty great, in my opinion. Creative Commons license, and hosted on GitHub so that anybody can contribute new icons to it.

[image]